# Use pandas to set a score of relations between columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm want to find relations between columns and create a new column with the score, but I'm lost and have no idea of how to do it.

Here are the columns I'm using

```
Yan     TNSeq   Kato    Eco-GeneOrth    Essential

accA    accA    accA        accA        accA    
accB    accB    accB        accB        accB    
accC    accC    accC        accC        accC    
accD    accD    accD        accD        accD    
aceF    acpP    acpP        alaS        aceF    
acpP    acpS    acpS        argA        acpP    
acpS    adk     adk         argB        acpS
```

What I want is to set a score between Essential and the other columns.

Like this:

```
Yan     TNSeq   Kato    Eco-GeneOrth    Essential   Score

accA    accA    accA        accA        accA        4
accB    accB    accB        accB        accB        4
accC    accC    accC        accC        accC        4
accD    accD    accD        accD        accD        4
aceF    acpP    acpP        alaS        aceF        1
acpP    acpS    acpS        argA        acpP        3  
acpS    adk     adk         argB        acpS        3
```

To give you some background, the first four columns are essential genes reported by the Authors, and the last column is the list of all essential genes for E.coli. And what I want is know how how many authors report the same essential genes with the full list.

Comment: Why are the last two columns scored 3? How is the score set up? And also your original data frame and result data frame don't seem to match.

Comment: Thanks. I copied the wrong column. I'll edit it

The last two columns are scored 3  because column two and three also have the value, even though they're not aligned.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
df['Score'] = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Yan', 'TNSeq', 'Kato', 'Eco-GeneOrth']).eq(df['Essential'], axis='rows').sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: This works, but my data set is large and not all of my genes are aligned.
Is there any other way to do this, or how can I align my data?

Comment: Please provide an example of not aligned data

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. There might be some performance issue if your data set is large, however, since your data is not aligned by row, I don't see a way around to avoid checking the whole data frame for every Essential gene:

```
import pandas as pd
def check(ess, col):
    return any(col.str.contains(ess))
df["Score"] = pd.Series(sum(df.loc[:,"Yan":"Eco-GeneOrth"].
                            apply(lambda col: check(ess, col), axis = 0)) for ess in df.Essential)

#    Yan    TNSeq   Kato    Eco-GeneOrth    Essential   Score
# 0 accA    accA    accA    accA    accA    4
# 1 accB    accB    accB    accB    accB    4
# 2 accC    accC    accC    accC    accC    4
# 3 accD    accD    accD    accD    accD    4
# 4 aceF    acpP    acpP    alaS    aceF    1
# 5 acpP    acpS    acpS    argA    acpP    3
# 6 acpS    adk     adk     argB    acpS    3
```

Comment: My data set is large. Now I think my problem is that my data is not aligned.
How can I align the other columns with my Essential list?
I've been trying with no luck